# How to find an average line from points?

Tags: c++, opencv

I detected contours using OpenCV and I want to find lines from the contours.

I found an example code to find a line from scatter plots.

```
// Construct line from points
bool ShapeDetection::FitPoints(const std::vector<cv::Point> &pts) {
  int nPoints = pts.size();
  if( nPoints < 2 ) {
    // Fail: infinitely many lines passing through this single point
    _slope = 0;
    _yInt = 0;
    return false;
  }
  double sumX=0, sumY=0, sumXY=0, sumX2=0;
  for(int i=0; i<nPoints; i++) {
    sumX += pts[i].x;
    sumY += pts[i].y;
    sumXY += pts[i].x * pts[i].y;
    sumX2 += pts[i].x * pts[i].x;
  }
  double xMean = sumX / nPoints;
  double yMean = sumY / nPoints;
  double denominator = sumX2 - sumX * xMean;
  // You can tune the eps (1e-7) below for your specific task
  if( std::fabs(denominator) < 1e-7 ) {
    // Fail: it seems a vertical line
    _slope = 0;
    _yInt = xMean;

    return false;
  }
  _slope = (sumXY - sumX * yMean) / denominator;
  _yInt = yMean - _slope * xMean;

  return true;
}
```

[image]

And it worked very well to find horizontal lines like the one above. But, it didn't find vertical lines, like this:

[image]

I have tried similar test on this website:
https://www.rapidtables.com/tools/scatter-plot.html

[image]

It had to show a vertical line close to 3 in h-axis, but not.

Which method should I use to solve it?

Comment: Vertical lines cannot fit Slope-Y model, because its slope is infinity. Maybe you can try other models, such as Point-Direction (represent the line with one point and one direction vector). It may also works by solving the linear equation `Ax+By+C=0`.

Comment: opencv has a fitLine function. If you expect dignificant outliers, you could tey to implement a RANSAC based approach.

Comment: @Micka Oh there is the easiest solution in OpenCV. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @VictorBian Thank you for your reply. Yes I think that is the problem. But I will just use the OpenCV function as Micka said.